# May I approve a suggested edit that removes an offensive word from code?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, offensive

Today I reviewed this suggested edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3251185

Here the editor removed an offensive word from the user's code. Is it right to edit the user's code in which he used the offensive word?

Comment: Seems like he meant to type "cont." anyway, as in continued.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes!

Of course it's okay. 
Actually it is recommended to change it if you see that.

### Keep in mind...

Make **100%** sure that it is not important in the code though. Otherwise, the edit is invalid.

Comment: "Make 100% sure that it is not important in the code though. Otherwise, the edit is invalid." - IOW, if you try to edit out the profanity from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6099598/922184), it's probably gonna get rejected.

Comment: @Mysticial That's a great answer on that linked question.

Answer (score 7):

I have to say that I'm not a huge fan of just blindly editing the word out like that. As [lunboks mentions in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203611/can-i-approve-the-offensive-word-removed-in-suggested-edit-in-code#comment649090_203611), he likely meant to use the word "cont" as a shortened form of "continued" - and a more helpful edit would be changing the *u* to an *o*.

Random swear words in the middle of the code like that are usually mistakes or oversights, and just editing them out (or replacing them with something unrelated) because "they're offensive" can cause more harm than good in the long-run. Here it's just in a string, so there's not much effect, but if he copy-pastes some code which has the changed version without the word, he's going to have a hell of a time debugging when all of a sudden his debug message just says "FMU with some text."

If you can't figure out why he typed it a certain way or what it's *supposed* to be, I'd be more of a fan of commenting and asking. If you're completely certain that the word is just there for the sake of the word being there, then by all means just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Given that it wasn't important for the sake of the question that it be there, absolutely.

Answer (score -4):

StackOverflow does not approve of offensive language. So please refrain from editing

Also, that is a word that is *extremely* offensive. I really hope we don't degrade to a point where that type of language is considered oK..

Comment: You are missing the point. He approved an edit to remove it.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - Rough day I guess, sorry!!!

Comment: What a great opportunity to get the peer pressure badge, isn't it?

Comment: @JanDvorak [He already has it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/36/peer-pressure?userid=164243)

Comment: @Servy hmm... should I be surprised about that?